# API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to follow [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) tutorial, but when I try to test the API I've created, I get the following message:

> API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role

The API request should be posting to a DynamoDB table I've created.

I've created an IAM Role and attached the policy AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess. I've also tried attaching this policy to my administrator user.

Here is the integration request in my API:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share the IAM policy you have attached to Lambda?

Comment: I am not using a Lambda function, only API Gateway and DynamoDB.

Comment: But how do you connect DynamoDB from API gateway?

Comment: Using an integration request with DynamoDB and it's function PutItem, as specified in the tutorial linked to in my original post.

Comment: Here is a similar more recent tutorial that has more details/screenshots, particularly including a focus on IAM (Policies, Roles, etc):  https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARN you have provided for the IAM Role is a policy. It needs to be a role. Please go to your generated role and update your ARN to that. It should look something like this `*:role/AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess-201709151726`

Comment: That is precisely what the trust relationship looks like for the role that has the AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess-201709151726 policy attached to it.

Comment: @SpencerGoff Actually, it looks like you have the ARN for the policy specified in the role field. Please attach the policy to a role then put the role ARN there.

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much @asdf. Want to post a new answer so I can mark it correct?

Answer (score 5):

Below worked for me

Go to IAM > Roles > whateverRole > Trust Relationships > Edit Trust Relationship and add apigateway under Statements

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

Assisted by this guy https://histerr.blogspot.com/2016/06/api-gateway-does-not-have-permission-to.html?showComment=1549214559316#c3046645274286738526