# Set policy and role in AWS to connect API Gateway and DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am trying stream data from the AWS API Gateway to DynamoDB in AWS (directly, without something like lambda). I have looked for several tutorials, such as [1] and [2], who describe exactly this scenario. All of these assume that the right policies and roles are in place. Normally, I play and hack around till I get a working proof of concept, after which I rebuild a proper model, but with access rights I want to make sure I understand what I am doing. For [2], I also found a stack overflow question at [3] from somebody with the same problem that got solved, but not sure exactly how. I also looked at [4], describing API Gateway with Lambda.

Here is my guess:

- Create a policy that allows calling from the API Gateway. 

  "AmazonAPIGatewayInvokeFullAccess" fits the name, but might not
  be necessary + overkill with too much access
- Create a policy that allows access to dynamoDB. 

  Here, "AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess" might be appropriate, even
  though it might be overkill (too much access), and might only work
  from the Management Console
- Create a role that has those two policies attached. 

  Here, I run into the trouble that when I click create role, and
  select AWS service, I can not find the correct "service that will use
  this role" that has the policies I described above behind it. For
  example, when clicking dynamoDB, I get the following "use-cases",  none of which seem to relate to the dynamoDB full access policy:

  - Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) - DynamoDB access
  - DynamoDB - Global Tables
  - DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) - Cluster management

My main question is: How do I set the right minimal set of roles and policies to connect AWS API Gateway to DynamoDB (read and write), as described in [1]?

[1] https://sanderknape.com/2017/10/creating-a-serverless-api-using-aws-api-gateway-and-dynamodb/
[2] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/
[3] [API Gateway does not have permission to assume the provided role DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282781/api-gateway-does-not-have-permission-to-assume-the-provided-role-dynamodb)
[4] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is create an IAM Service Role that allows API Gateway to assume this role. You can easily do this through the UI. When you create a new role, the "Service Role" is selected by default and below the "Choose the service that will use this role" header, you can select API Gateway.

A role is a container of permissions that can be assumed by a certain entity (in our case, an API Gateway API resource). Your role needs "permissions" for the role to have any use. You add this permissions by adding policies to your role. This is explained more in depth here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_terms-and-concepts.html

Be sure to read the AWS Service Role part. You say that you need to "Create a policy that allows calling from the API Gateway" but this is incorrect: you need to create a *role* that can be *assumed* by API Gateway.

In your case, you'll want specific DynamoDB permissions for your role. Following the least-privilege principle as you mention, you should only add the specific actions for the specific DynamoDB table. The list of possible permissions can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html

Let's say you only want API Gateway to get items from a specific table. Your policy might look something like this then:

```
{
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "dynamodb:GetItem",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:[aws_account_id]:table/[table_name]"
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This mostly solved my answer. I still had the issue that my policy would not show up in the correct category during creation. First creating an empty role, after which assigning a policy to the role after the creation solved it, as this exposed a different UI. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This recent new tutorial by ankana likhita sri priya includes starting off in high detail/screenshots of IAM (Policy, Role, etc.):  https://medium.com/@likhita507/using-api-gateway-to-get-data-from-dynamo-db-using-without-using-aws-lambda-e51434a4f5a0